# Grouping levels - multiindex in python pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I've a [multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) [dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe) in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) that looks this (created using [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)):

[image]

I need help to add a level above (or below) the Date level showing the day of the date like this:

[image]

I know I can get the day of a date like this:

```
lt.DATE.dt.strftime('%a')
#lt is a dataframe and DATE is a column it.
```

Here is the code reporduce a similar pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dlist = pd.date_range('2015-01-01',periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(dlist, columns=['DATE'])
df['EC'] = range(7033,7033+len(df))
df['HS'] = np.random.randint(0,9,5)
df['AH'] = np.random.randint(0,9,5)
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=[df.DATE, 'EC'], values=['HS','AH'])
pv = pv.unstack(level=1).unstack(level=0)
```

Comment: Please post real code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added sample code to produce a similar pivot_table :)

Comment: @FabioLamanna I appreciate you for asking code, that made me create a sample code and out of which I got the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution! Here it goes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dlist = pd.date_range('2015-01-01',periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(dlist, columns=['DATE'])
df['EC'] = range(7033,7033+len(df))
df['HS'] = np.random.randint(0,9,5)
df['AH'] = np.random.randint(0,9,5)
df['DAY'] = df.DATE.dt.strftime('%a')
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=[df.DATE.dt.date, df.DAY, 'EC'], values=['HS','AH'])
pv = pv.unstack(level=[1,2]).unstack(level=0)
pv.to_excel('solution.xlsx')
```

And it produces an output like this:

[image]

Pay attention to the function [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) and set the list of levels that are required to be unstacked at a time.